# Question is how to deal with customer that is not paying through proper website channel and goes on increasing his offer?

Tags: freelance-websites, payment-terms

Yesterday i got an offer from a client to give 1500 reviews and 50 post on his social account,The client offered me $250 but he was saying that i will pay you by paypal not through website pay channel.i said to him that i will start my job until you send payment through proper site channel now he goes on increases his offer.I'm now confused whether i accept it or not? There is also a risk involve in this as after job completion possibility that he will not pay so what should i do?

Answer (score 2):

Do not budge on this. If you have an acceptable payment channel established already and this client reached out to you through this platform, then there is no reason he should be demanding you to use another service. Furthermore, no sensible client would substantially increase the amount they are willing to pay strictly on the basis of be allowed to use Paypal over your trusted payment method.

This client may be legitimate, but they are acting in a suspicious manner that suggests unknown ulterior motives.